# How can I connect a cassette player to my Macbook (Mid 2015) to record cassette tapes on my mac?

Tags: audio

I tried connecting the two headphone jacks to each other but the Mac is not recognizing this as an input source. I also have a cord to connect the headphone jack on the cassette player to a USB but the Mac isn't recognizing that either.

What is the proper way to go about this? I know nothing about cords and inputs/outputs. I want to somehow feed the audio from the cassette to the Mac to eventually be able to digitize the audio on the cassette tapes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QXYVZQQ), or something similar. It connects to the USB port on your Mac. The app [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/mac/) will digitize the audio. I've used this device from [Behringer](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/UFO202--behringer-u-phono-ufo202-usb-audio-interface-with-phono-preamp) for this exact purpose.

Comment: Perfect! This should work...thanks!

Comment: Question: is there a technical reason why I need a separate device to do this? Why can't I simply hook the cassette player up to the computer with the headphone jack and usb only?

Comment: I believe the headphone/microphone jack on the Macbook is designed for mic levels, not line levels from the cassette player. [This page](https://www.thebroadcastbridge.com/content/entry/7578/the-difference-between-line-and-mic-level-audio) may give some insight.